# How to transpose a table column data into an array, preserving data format (as string or text)

Tags: excel, vba, text, transpose, listobject

I have a table that contains  two columns. One (C1) is populated with numbers formatted with two decimals like 2584.12. The other column (C2) contains also numbers that are written now and then, with different formats.

At the worksheet change event, scoped on that second column, the code applies to C2 the same (edit: not the same format but different) format applied in C1.

For referencing the format used in C1 I'm using arrays containing an entire column:

```
Set mytable = worksheet.ListObjects("My_Table")
colarray = Application.Transpose(mytable.ListColumns("C1").DataBodyRange)
```

, but "mytable.ListColumns("C1").DataBodyRange" reads the numbers as values not as text.

My problem occurs when, in C1, the reference number decimals are zeroes, like "2584.00" which in array is stored as integer value like "2584", even the table number is stored as text with two zero decimals as "2584.00"

I'd like to know if there is a way to use this method of transposing a table column to an array so it can retain the numbers as text, in order to avoid the problem with zero decimals.

I'm thinking that I have to use some .Text property on the DataBodyRange but I cannot get a working result, so the next won't work ("Invalid number of arguments"):

```
colarray = Application.Transpose(mytable.ListColumns("C1").DataBodyRange.Text)
```

The .Text property works very well addressing a single cell from the table, for example:

```
debug.print mytable.ListColumns("C1").DataBodyRange.rows(1).Text
```

results "2584.00" as oposed to"2584" from colarray(1).

Surely I could find another way for my purpose but, for the speed advantage I would stick to the transpose method of an entire column.

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is about so the correct person can answer. Is it about Excel and VBA perhaps (at a guess)?

Comment: Oooh! Thanks Brian! It's about Excel VBA. I added the excel vba tag.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to use an array of strings.... but I don't know what you're doing with the data so that may not be practical for you.

```
dim myArray(1 to 1) as string
myArray(1) = "123.00"
```

will always be 123.00

Comment: Thanks ProfoundlyOblivious! The problem is that i don't know how to correctly use some ListObject properties. I've reformulated my question!

Comment: I've gotta be crazy for even suggesting this....  if the value is a whole number then disintegerize (yes i made that up) it by adding .001

Comment: i don't believe the text property will work for you. if it's critical that the array holds the decimal value then i think you have to use a string. if the displayed value is the important part then format() is your friend.  I'm curious why you're transposing a single column. then you read the column aren't you only getting a 1 dimensional array? (1 to n )  I'd swear up and down that's what I've been using in my tables for columns and i haven't been transposing anything.  also, fwiw, the terminology for tables drives me nuts and took me longer to understand than i would like to admit.

Comment: It's critical that the array holds the decimal zeroes but it's not the fault of transpose or array but my lack of using of LIstObject properties. I'm using only one column arrays because it easier to address or pinpoint the sheet_change event, at least of advantages.

Comment: strings are my only solution.... and that likely requires  testing every element in the array for a decimal point as the third character from the right and changing those that fail the test.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the .Text (as .Value and others) property cannot be applied for multiple cells in one range, but only for one cell, for reading. So I have to find another way to fit my needs.

This code works:

```
colarray = Application.Transpose(mytable.ListColumns("C1").DataBodyRange.rows(1).Text)
```

and this one don't:

```
colarray = Application.Transpose(mytable.ListColumns("C1").DataBodyRange.Rows("1:6").Text)
```

Thank you!